# Check for one or more space in a word using regex

Tags: c#, regex

My scenario:

I am trying to find space in a single word(PK_myid) in a sentence. Eg :

```
"ID is PK_myid some more words"
```

Note the "some more words" is fixed and will always be the same.

I been able to write this part so far :

```
(?Id\s+is\s+(\w+\s+\w+\s+)+some)
```

This only check for one space between the word though,i can have multiple space like the below

```
"PK_ my id"
```

Comment: Down-voters should take note of _"**I** been able to **write this part so far** `(?Id\s+is\s+(\w+\s+\w+\s+)+some) `"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\bID\s+is\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)\s+some\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyppCj/2). *Details*:

- `\bID` - whole word `ID`
- `\s+is\s+` - `is` word enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero or more occurrences (but as few as possible) of one or more whitespaces and word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `some\b` - a whole word `some`.

In C#, to get the first occurrence, you can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Match(text, @"\bID\s+is\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)\s+some\b")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

To get all matches:

```cs
var output = Regex.Matches(text, @"\bID\s+is\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)\s+some\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/PUTrFZ):

```cs
var line = "ID is PK_myid some more words\nID is PK_ my id some more words";
var pattern = @"\bID\s+is\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)\s+some\b";
var output = Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
foreach (var s in output)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```cs
PK_myid
PK_ my id
```

Comment: The issue it still matches for (PK_myid) if there is no space.

Comment: @KeshavTaurah If there must be a space, replace `*?` with `+?`, `\bID\s+is\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)+?)\s+some\b`